# powershell 2.0 redirection file handle exception

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, file-io, powershell-2.0

I'm looking for a solution to the `The OS handle's position is not what FileStream expected. Do not use a handle simultaneously in one FileStream and in Win32 code or another FileStream.` exception that would also work on scripts called within the script containing ["the fix"](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/07/30/workaround-the-os-handles-position-is-not-what-filestream-expected/).

For the purposes of this question, say that I have two scripts:

**foo.ps1**

```
# <fix>
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$objectRef = $host.GetType().GetField( "externalHostRef", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $host )
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetProperty"
$consoleHost = $objectRef.GetType().GetProperty( "Value", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $objectRef, @() )
[void] $consoleHost.GetType().GetProperty( "IsStandardOutputRedirected", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $consoleHost, @() )
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$field = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardOutputWriter", $bindingFlags )
$field.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
$field2 = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardErrorWriter", $bindingFlags )
$field2.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
# </fix>

write-host "normal"
write-error "error"
write-host "yay"
.\bar.ps1
```

**bar.ps1**

```
write-host "normal"
write-error "error"
write-host "yay"
```

And `foo.ps1` is being run like this:

```
powershell .\foo.ps1 > C:\temp\redirecct.log 2>&1
```

The expected output should be:

```
normal
C:\foo.ps1 : error
At line:1 char:10
+ .\foo.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,foo.ps1

yay
normal
C:\bar.ps1 : error
At C:\foo.ps1:17 char:6
+ .\bar <<<<  2>&1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,bar.ps1

yay
```

However, due to the known bug, the output is actually:

```
normal
C:\foo.ps1 : error
At line:1 char:10
+ .\foo.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,foo.ps1

yay
normal
out-lineoutput : The OS handle's position is not what FileStream expected. Do not use a handle simultaneously in one FileStream and in Win3
2 code or another FileStream. This may cause data loss.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [out-lineoutput], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```

So the observed behavior is that the changes made by "the fix" aren't being inherited by the 'child' script (`bar.ps1`, in this case).  When bar.ps1 tries to write, it crashes hard.  If I don't guard against it somehow in `foo.ps1`, it will also crash hard.  What can I do before/in calling `bar.ps1` to prevent `bar.ps1` from crashing when it tries to write?

Constraints:

- Powershell 2.0
- The script must be run as above
- I can't modify bar.ps1 (and it should not crash when writing to stderr).

**UPDATE**

Below is a half-acceptable solution.  I say half because it only prevents the 'parent' script from crashing.  The 'child' script still fails hard when it tries to write.  On the plus side, it can go as far as recognizing that bar failed.

**foo.ps1**:

```
function savepowershellfromitself {
    $bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
    $objectRef = $host.GetType().GetField( "externalHostRef", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $host )
    $bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetProperty"
    $consoleHost = $objectRef.GetType().GetProperty( "Value", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $objectRef, @() )
    [void] $consoleHost.GetType().GetProperty( "IsStandardOutputRedirected", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $consoleHost, @() )
    $bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
    $field = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardOutputWriter", $bindingFlags )
    $field.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
    $field2 = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardErrorWriter", $bindingFlags )
    $field2.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
}

savepowershellfromitself
write-host "normal"
write-error "error"
write-host "yay"
$output = .\bar.ps1 2>&1
savepowershellfromitself
write-host "$output"
if( $errors = $output | ?{$_.gettype().Name -eq "ErrorRecord"} ){
    write-host "there were errors in bar!"
}
write-error "error2"
write-host "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this in foo.ps1 it solves the problem:

```
# <fix>
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$objectRef = $host.GetType().GetField( "externalHostRef", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $host )
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetProperty"
$consoleHost = $objectRef.GetType().GetProperty( "Value", $bindingFlags ).GetValue(     $objectRef, @() )
[void] $consoleHost.GetType().GetProperty( "IsStandardOutputRedirected", $bindingFlags).GetValue( $consoleHost, @() )
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$field = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardOutputWriter", $bindingFlags )
$field.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
$field2 = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardErrorWriter", $bindingFlags )
$field2.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
# </fix>

write-host "normal"
write-error "error"
write-host "yay"

powershell .\bar.ps1 2>&1 | more
```

Piping the output through more hides the fact that it is ultimately going to a file from the child instance of Powershell, bypassing the bug.

In fact, if you create a grandparent script foobar.ps1 which just runs foo.ps1:

```
powershell .\foo.ps1 2>&1 | more
```

Then you don't need "the fix" at all, and foo.ps1 can just be

```
write-host "normal"
write-error "error"
write-host "yay"

.\bar.ps1
```

because the piping solves the problem for all descendent scripts.

Comment: Note: foobar.ps1 should probably check whether the output is redirected or not before calling foo.ps1; if it isn't redirected, it probably shouldn't be piped to more.

Comment: thanks for your answer!  i actually experimented with the idea of a common parent-wrapper script today.  instead of more though, i found success with something like `$output = invoke-command "$args 2>&1" (extended from what i showed above).  also, i appreciate you taking a look at all 3 of these open questions :)