# powershell 2.0 command line redirection

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, file-io, powershell-2.0

I'm looking for an explanation of the following discrepancy:

Given the following powershell script **foo.ps1**:

```
write-host "normal"
write-error "error"
write-host "yay"
```

Running it with

`C:\>powershell .\foo.ps1 > out.txt 2>&1`

Produces:

```
normal
C:\foo.ps1 : error
At line:1 char:10
+ .\foo.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,foo.ps1

Write-Host : The OS handle's position is not what FileStream expected. Do not use a handle simultaneously in one FileStream and in Win32 co
de or another FileStream. This may cause data loss.
At C:\foo.ps1:3 char:11
+ write-host <<<<  "yay"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Host], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand
```

But running with:

`C:\>powershell .\foo.ps1 2>&1 > out.txt`

Produces (correctly):

```
normal
C:\foo.ps1 : error
At line:1 char:10
+ .\foo.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,foo.ps1

yay
```

I almost resolved myself into thinking that the order of the redirection mattered in Windows, however all of the examples in the [TechNet usage page for command redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) show the file redirection preceding the stderr redirection.

**Can someone please explain this to me?**

For reference, this is being done on Server 2003 x64 SP2 with:

```
C:\>powershell get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : 53c90e87-ded1-44f9-8e8d-6baaa1335420
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

and using write-output produces the same result.

(This question is related to my work in solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978052/powershell-2-0-redirection-file-handle-exception).)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I do know that Write-Host gets treated differently from all the other Write cmdlets. I avoid it like the plague now. Try your test with Write-Output.

Comment: thanks for the tip! unfortunately, the same result occurs.

Comment: Write-Output and Write-Host have very different purposes. Write-Host writes information (text) to the PowerShell host. Write-Output writes an object to the PowerShell pipeline, which can then be intercepted and processed by a command that accepts pipeline input. If no such command is used, then the object output is rendered to the host also.

Comment: Clearly cmd.exe is behaving differently in the two different cases.  However, since the behaviour isn't documented, it probably isn't a good idea to depend on it as a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in PowerShell 2.0.  I tried reproducing with the [PowerShell 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27548) preview and it now works as expected.

Comment: do you have a... happier answer?

Comment: Upgrade to the CTP, report the issue to Msft <shrug>