# powershell behavior when host file handle is closed

Tags: windows, perl, powershell, file-io, powershell-2.0

I'm looking for an explanation (preferably documentation) of the following madness.

Say I have the following simple Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $output = "C:\\Temp\\aout.txt";
my $outpute = "C:\\Temp\\aoute.txt";
my $command = "powershell C:\\test.ps1";

close STDOUT;
close STDERR;
if ( (my $pid = fork()) == 0 ) {
    open (STDOUT,">>$output") or die "cannot open $output as stdout: $!";
    open (STDERR,">>$outpute") or die "cannot open $outpute as stderr: $!";
    exec $command or die "couldn't exec $command: $!";
} else {
    my $ret = waitpid($pid,0);
}
```

And that the Powershell script contains:

```
write-output "yay1";
write-error "nay2";
write-output "yay3";
write-error "nay4";
write-output "yay5";
write-error "nay6";
write-output "yay7";
write-error "nay8";
write-host "done!";
```

If I run the Perl script, it produces two files, as expected, with the following output:

**aout.txt:**

```
yay1
yay3
yay5
yay7
done!
```

**aoute.txt:**

```
C:\test.ps1 : nay2
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

C:\test.ps1 : nay4
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

C:\test.ps1 : nay6
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

C:\test.ps1 : nay8
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1
```

If I modify the Perl script to keep STDERR closed before executing Powershell:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $output = "C:\\Temp\\aout.txt";
my $command = "powershell C:\\test.ps1";

close STDOUT;
close STDERR;
if ( (my $pid = fork()) == 0 ) {
    open (STDOUT,">>$output") or die "cannot open $output as stdout: $!";
    exec $command or die "couldn't exec $command: $!";
} else {
    my $ret = waitpid($pid,0);
}
```

Then it produces one STDOUT file with *all* of the output:

```
yay1
C:\\test.ps1 : nay2
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

yay3
C:\\test.ps1 : nay4
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

yay5
C:\\test.ps1 : nay6
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

yay7
C:\\test.ps1 : nay8
At line:1 char:41
+ C:\\test.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

done!
```

**Is Powershell really realizing that STDERR is closed, and is doing a clean redirect onto STDOUT?  Or is it the command line console?  Or is it Perl?**

For reference, this is on Windows Server 2003 x64 SP2 with:

```
C:\>perl --version

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
(with 33 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall

Binary build 819 [267479] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Aug 27 2006 22:13:23

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.


C:\>powershell get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : 1ac67afa-f020-414c-b47b-031bdc8cc703
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

and this is part of an ongoing effort related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978052/powershell-2-0-redirection-file-handle-exception) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065296/powershell-2-0-command-line-redirection).

Comment: I would suggest trying the same thing in another programming language.  If it does the same thing, it's either powershell or something in how exec works on Windows.

Comment: I don't know; does it matter?  What do you want to happen?

Comment: i want a clear understanding of how shell redirection affects powershell.  i want to know when to expect it to cash and when to expect it to behave.

Comment: Powershell isn't anything like other programming languages.  I really have to isolate myself in powershell-land when it comes time to write some PS.  PS programs are a totally different animal, what you're calling output redirection is actually pipeline manipulation.  It's not exactly accurate to say it's "buggy", you're just doing two completely different things that appear to be the same on the surface.  Apples and oranges.